# Change to Django model not detected by makemigrations

Tags: django, migration

I have a Django model which is referenced in another model as a `ForeignKey` type. In order that this is displayed nicely in the admin interface I added a `__unicode__` method, like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.label
```

This change is immediately visible in the admin interface after saving my models.py file. But when I run `makemigrations` it returns `No changes detected in app 'foo'`. Running `migrate` does nothing, as it doesn't see any changes, and `python manage.py check` returns `System check identified no issues (0 silenced).`

Should I expect this? I've made many changes to my models and so have run many migrations (including this week), but I've never encountered this before.

Currently running Django 1.8.3 with Sqlite development db, under Python 2.7 on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be alright. Migrations are only created, if the **model's structure** is changed, aka if you add any new vars to the model.

As new methods are concerned, as they don't change the model's structure, no migration is required. So you can happily add methods to your model w/o running a single migration.

If the name is not displayed in django's admin backend, try using the method `__str__` instead. that worked for me (but running Python 3.5 on linux).

```
def __str__ ( self ):
    return self.name
```

Comment: That's great, thank you. I did suspect as much. I should indeed update my Python, though, and use `__str__` instead.